# How do you enable webpack experiments option in quasar js framework?

Tags: webpack, quasar-framework

In https://quasar.dev I would like to enable webpack 5 experimental features so I can load a wasm easily.

According to webpack I need to add the below to my `module.exports` webpack config.

```
experiments: {
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
    syncWebAssembly: true
  },
```

Since quasar has it's own config where do I enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled over the same problem. You can enable it like this:

```
extendWebpack(cfg) {
  cfg.experiments = {
    asyncWebAssembly: true
  }
},
```

Furthermore you need to delete the `chainWebpack` function and, if you want to keep the settings defined there, move them to the `extendWebpack` function.

Comment: Great, This should be in `build` block & chainWebpack can stay there at this time.